# How to open a file inside a folder which is in the same folder as a Python program?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Basically I am looking for a simple way to open text file in a folder that is inside the same folder as the program.
My directory structure looks like this:

`/programfolder/textfiles/textfile`

And I'm trying to use open like this:

```
text=functionthatgetsfilename()
file=open("textfiles/"+text,"r")
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I just have a typo somewhere?

Comment: Tried \ instead of /?

Comment: Yes I have it did not work.

Comment: What would that look like anyways mabye I have just made a simple mistake.....

Comment: Is fucnctionthatgetsfilename() returning the name and extension, or just the name?

Comment: Why don't you print the filename once first? Also, try changing the opening mode to `a+` and see where the file got created; then you know where Python is looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the difference between the *Current Directory* and the directory your script is in. Your current directory is the directory that you started the application from, in the command line (CMD, SH, etc). You can show that with `os.path.normpath(os.curdir)`.

To solve your problem, you can use

```
file=open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'holdstextfiles',text),'r')
```

or

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
...
```

The first solution uses the absolute path to your desired file, which is the same no matter what: it's *absolute*

The second solution changes the current directory before trying to use the *relative* path that you're using.